# Eclipse C/C++ import settings: Not sure what to do

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk

There are no settings on my android project for C/C++ build. I tried importing the settings and its asking for an xml file. I've installed Android NDK, CDT, and I'm trying to run the OpenCV4Android library here. I also get this error in additional:

Error: Program "C:\Users\Prateek Chachra\Downloads\android-ndk-r11c-windows-x86\ndk-build.cmd" not found in PATH

Even though I've added this in the settings. I want to run the sample project and despite of having installed everything needed it still gives an error. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to environment variable %PATH% that path.
Shortly, this error means that the directory where ndk-build.cmd is located can't be found in the PATH env. var, in which are specified binaries directories

Comment: My problem is the C/C++ settings aren't appearing. The path is added to the environment variables, but the project is set to an android project.

Comment: Try android studio instead of Eclipse. Eclipse is not anymore supported by Google ;)